# Avoid csrf token in django post method

Tags: django, post, django-rest-framework, csrf-token

I am making part of the web app where (unlogged users, all visitors) can fill the form and I have to save that data (name, phone number, question) in database..
I am making REST using Django, but for frontend I will use React or Django, and I am making POST method in Django framework that reads JSON data from POST https request, and then I save that data to database.. But I get error CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. because I don not use CSRF token, because it is not required for this (I do not have logged users).
But I do not want to disable CSRF, because for admin page I would use this to authenticate users?
So anyone knows how to avoid using CSRF token for this method? Thanks in advance..

```
def saveDataToDatabase(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        json_data = json.loads(request.body) 
        try:
            data = json_data['data']
        except KeyError:
            HttpResponseServerError("Malformed data!")
```

This is the part of method..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to disable csrf protection on a view with `@csrf_exempt` decorator.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def saveDataToDatabase(request):
    # Your code here
```

More [Infos on the Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.2/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using Views to handle the requests? You may use these so you don´t have to do the next advice I´m giving you.

If the first advice wasn´t good enough, you may disable the csrf token in the settings file from Django. You need to remove (or comment) the **`django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware`** in the available Middleware list.

Any other question just ask. ;)