# How can I disable Django's csrf protection only in certain cases so that the sessionid and csrftoken won't display in the browser console?

Tags: django

I have developed a django app with some APIs now the requirement is that I should not allow the app to display the session_id and csrftoken being displayed in the browser.

I have read the docs and other article on how to disable csrf on a view [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70204136/avoid-csrf-token-in-django-post-method) I did that but still it appears in the browser see screenshot below.

Thank you for your helps in advance.

[image]